# Not able to view articles in community

Tags: community, knowledge, articles, partner-portal, lightning-knowledge

I have a partner community and I have done below steps as per this video-

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oKRFsKQCp8c&t=88s

1.Enabled Knowledge

2.Created FAQ record type for knowledge

3. Created Articled

4.Made it available to everyone including partner community
5. Created Topic

6.Assigned topic to Article

7.Added topic to Featured topic
8.Added Featured topic component to page (in builder)

However, I am not able to view the article while clicking on the topic.

I am seeing this:- 
[[image: Image landing[1]]

I am expecting to see this:-
[image: Expected]

Comment: Is Knowledge User Liscense required for Portal User?

Comment: Have you given read access to the customer's profiles for your article record type? https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_knowledge_access.htm&type=5